# If we remove "powered by Google" while using google translator API, violates the T&C of Google?

Tags: api, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit, attribution

If we remove "powered by Google" while using google translator API does it violate the T&C of Google? In [attribution requirements](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution) it is given but I am not sure whether it is legal or not to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to leave the "Powered by Google" which is within the terms you accepted in order to use the API. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution),

> Use of these APIs is governed by the Terms of Service. Among other things, these Terms require that you adhere to certain guidelines on how lay out, Google attribution, and branding must be handled on your site. This document and the HTML Markup Requirements are intended to help you meet these requirements.

Since you signed/accepted these terms, you are required to follow them. In addition, in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution) is also mentioned,

> If you are uncomfortable with any of these branding guidelines, discontinue your use of the API, and [contact](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/translation-attiribution/) us with your concerns.

For this reason, you should contact Google and discontinue the API's usage if you do not desire following all the requirements.

Lastly, under [Attribution and logos](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution#attribution_and_logos),

> In addition to following Google's general Brand Features guidelines, you are also required to adopt certain branding elements when using the Cloud Translation API.
>
> ...
>
> - The "powered by Google Translate" graphic must always be displayed adjacent any translation results.